# Do anyone know how really B2B App distribution works in Apple?

Tags: ios, b2b, apple-vpp

I have been developing an iOS App since 3 years and in the last update I send to App Store Connect they reject it due to they told me that my application din't obey the rules that an app should follow in the App Store.

This means that my app don't target a regular App Store user, they only can login to my App if they hire my company's services.

So then they "recommended us" (obligated us) to distribute our App by B2B distribution.

As I have been reading the way it works is to sign up each of our clients to the B2B program. I hope this could be wrong because we have more than 10000 users that we can't manage their Apple ID to add them to our B2B program one by one.

Do exists another way to distribute my App like give to my user a key/url to let them join to our B2B program or what?

I think that I am missing something.

Thanks for your help, all information I have tried to get from Apple web page is cumbersome and I have tried to talk with them but they only send me Emails 1 per day and with no really relevant info like they don't wanna know about me.

Comment: I have a B2B app, and a user can create account/sign in for free. Simply add a login/signup for users

Comment: Are they 10,000 individual users or thousands of users that work for one or a few companies.  If they are individuals, then you probably need to go back to Apple as your app probably isn't a candidate for B2B distribution. B2B would normally be used where your customer is actually an organisation that wants to distribute the app to their employees.  There are lots of apps in the store that only work with a login; banking apps for example, so the criteria is generality rather than the fact that there is a login.  If your target is individual users you may want to add IAP to your app

Comment: They are 10000 users but divided in a lot of enterprises. We serve our services to any enterprise hire our services. It means that we have like 100 or 200 enterprises with their employees, and they all makes the around 10000 users of our apps.

Comment: The problem is that I see myself obligated to force to each of our users (employees of our clients) create an account to B2B where a lot of our clients are people with 50 or more years old that cannot really explain all the process I guess...

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I was involved in project that was suited for B2B distribution since they were used by employees of organisation. So, we recently had adopted B2B but there were lots of issues and lack of response from apple. Initially we used redemption codes for distribution which was very tedious and the major problem was that -  the employees could not update the app. We also tried for MDM solution but that really did not suite our requirements. Eventually we made our app public again so that users could easily receive updates. We are now transitioning to Container App to avoid app rejection.

Comment: Hi, today I finally reached to download my B2B app by Redeem Codes but, the updates doesn't do automatically? There is a thing I didn't know! :S